# git rebase after push origin master

Tags: git, github

I was able to successfully rebase ( using/like git rebase -i HEAD~3 ) but once I git push origin master I get strange messages such as for the same rebase command:

```
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git reset'
rebase in progress; onto 67c7420
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '67c7420'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
Could not apply 16aeb8c44f170c9e96777d529d8cf74963aa042a...
```

once I tried --allow-empty and still didnt work
Is it possible to rebase my last 3 commit messages after i did push origin master?